# Why is custom navigation bar button image stretched?

Tags: ios, image, button, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I tried to add a navigation bar button with custom image. However, whatever method I use, the image always appears stretched.

**Method 1:**

```
    let barbuttonitem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "apps_small"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbuttonitem
```

It appears like this:

[image: Method 1]

**Method 2:**

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "apps_small"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TeachingRootViewController.appsTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

It appears like this:

[image: Method 2]

**Method 3:**

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "apps_small"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 300)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.imageInsets = .init(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 300)
```

It looks like this:

[image: Method 3]

As you can see the title is gone.

In the UI Hierarchy, it looks like this:

[image: UI Hierarchy]

It appears that the button has taken up all spaces in the navigation bar.

However, there is no problem for button with a system item:

[image: System item]

Is there anybody who knows the reason for this problem? I think I have run out of ideas.

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above answer is a workaround and not a proper fix.
The correct answer is you should have generate your photos with the correct sizes

- asset@1x: 22x22px
- asset@2x: 44x44px
- asset@3x: 66x66px

Answer (score 3):

Try adding it as a subView instead of setting it as the leftBarButtonItem

```
var leftButton = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
var background = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "apps_small"))
background.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
leftButton.addSubview(background)
self.navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(leftButton)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! However it won't compile... The compiler complains that "Value of type 'UINavigationItem' has no member 'addSubview'". UIBarButtonItem also doesn't have 'addSubview'.

Comment: I am not creating a UIBarButtonItem .. ill edit this to use the navController.. so you can try again

Comment: @imxieyi can you try again with a UIButton and a UINavigationBar as the code I provided?

Comment: Okay... It works... Although this solution looks a little strange to me... I'm still wondering why is my previous method corrupt...

Answer (score 3):

> As per my experience, You have faced this issue because you're added large size images for all `resolution 1X, 2X and 3X`. You need
>   to scale it down to a size more appropriate for the navigation bar.

## Solution: 1

You need to scale it down to a size more appropriate for the navigation bar. Please have look image sizes for `UINavigationBar`

> asset@1X Size: 24X24
>
> asset@2X Size: 48X48
>
> asset@3X Size: 72X72

## Solution: 2

If you want to go with the same images then you need to do below changes in your code.

You just need to add `UIImageView` inside the `UIView` then everything
works as expected.

## Code:

```
    let containerView = UIControl(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    containerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSearch), for: .touchUpInside)
    let imageSearch = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    imageSearch.image = UIImage(named: "search")
    containerView.addSubview(imageSearch)                
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containerView)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's all about the Image size that you put inside your UIButton.**

If you are using UIButton as a custom view for

```
UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

and inside that custom button, you are setting an image. It is better to set the image size to something you need.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image")!.resizeImage(newWidth: 25), for: .normal)
```

And this is a good extension for resizing images in your app. it is using CoreGraphic to resize.

```
extension UIImage{
    //Resize image
    func resizeImage(newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let originalImage = self
        
        let scale = newWidth / self.size.width
        let newHeight = self.size.height * scale
        
        let newImage = self.resizeWithCoreGraphics(to: CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)) ?? originalImage
        
        return newImage
    }
    
    private func resizeWithCoreGraphics(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage, let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else { return nil }
        
        let width = Int(newSize.width)
        let height = Int(newSize.height)
        let bitsPerComponent = cgImage.bitsPerComponent
        let bytesPerRow = cgImage.bytesPerRow
        let bitmapInfo = cgImage.bitmapInfo
        
        guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                      bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }
        context.interpolationQuality = .high
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize)
        context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
        
        return context.makeImage().flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0) }
    }
}
```